# Has the approach of any protein digesting enzyme has been trialled for Progressive Supranuclear Palsy against a protein accumulation in brain cells?

Tags: brain

PSP -the degenerative disorder is attributed to accumulation of a protein in brain cells. Has any work been done to approach it by digesting this protein?

Comment: We ask that questions show evidence of prior research effort.

Comment: How would you digest such a protein without also digesting other proteins in the cell. How would you get this protease into the brain and into the cells?

Comment: I think the word "digesting" is the wrong choice. You digest a meal (non-discriminatory/encompasses almost everything in your stomach. Same with your example using proteases/other.) You want to research "tau-**targeted** therapy".